# No gradle file shown while importing project in android studio 0.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to import existing project into android studio 0.5.2 . When i select import project and go to the project it displays the build.gradle file along with project tree . following is the screenshot:[image]

But when i select project it asks me to give link to the gradle home and when i give it manually it gives me error-"location not correct" and i don't get build.gradle file there for selection.(In this case the above build.gradle) file is not shown.How can i make it work??

Comment: What file are you selecting to import? Selecting the parent folder or the top-level build.gradle file should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my mistake .Hope it helps others with the same problem .
First of all you have to select the build.gradle file and not the project while importing into android studio and for the gradle home you have to give the location of the installed gradle file in my case it was c:\androidstudio\plugins\gradle.
Also do not forget to change the gradle version and sdk build tools version in build.gradle file and change version of gradle in wrapper-properties.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and copy directory 'gradle' from it to your project's directory.