# The project is not a Gradle-based project. How do I open the project from the root directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been having this issue for a while and have been racking my brain.

I googled this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752077/no-gradle-file-shown-while-importing-project-in-android-studio-0-5-2)

Which the response is "Make sure you open the project from its root directory. i.e. the directory which contains the top level build.gradle file."

My question is:  How the do I do that if I cloned the project from bitbucket?

Here's a screenshot of my file tree:
[image: screen]

Thank you for any insights

Edit: Gradle files

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'
def JacksonVersion = '2.6.0'
def GPSVersion = '6.5.87'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.0.0'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "appname"
        logLevel 'TRACE'
        logAppenderConsole 'true'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VCS project import not working on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780644/vcs-project-import-not-working-on-android-studio)

Comment: @Chisko Here's my question, If i set this up, will I have to make two projects, copy and paste my changes into the VCS project even though it wont be able to run?  Plus the the VCS version has a lot of external dependencies.

Comment: No. As per my answer: "Importing a project like that implies (for AS) that your are importing a module, not starting a new project.". You need to create a project, then you can have any modules inside it.

Comment: @Chisko thank you for your help.  By looking at my screenshot, where would those external dependencies go?  Do you see the structure?  How can I import just a module into an empty project without creating a new project?

Comment: Let us see the contents of `build.gradle`, no picture please

Comment: @Chisko which level build.gradle?

Comment: Both. Please also clarify what do you mean by dependencies. Do you mean a module that you have the source code for? A JAR? Or a normal external dependency?

Comment: @Chisko gradle files added.  Dependencies referred to a collection of JAR files that are two levels above "app" in the directory.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a special reason you are using such an old gradle plugin version (1.2.3). Current version is 3.1.3. If you are using a current AS version this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Chisko Thanks for pointing that out.  I just updated that, but it still says this isn't a gradle based project.  Doing invalidate cache/restart as we speak

Comment: I'm confused why you haven't reached the point yet where you make a brand new project and only copy `src/main/java`. Then add in dependencies into the generated Gradle files until it builds

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your project is not Gradle based because `settings.gradle` and `bulid.gradle` are not in the IDE project directory, they are in that blacked-out subfolder under `.idea` and `.gradle` in your picture.

You must close this project. Open that **other folder** as an Android Studio Project, regardless of where you got that project from.

For library projects in Github, it would look like this. Anyone can clone this as-is and open as a project.

For apps, replace `sample` with `app`, and remove `library`

[image]

---

Most importantly, `buildscript` and `allprojects` section should not be in `/app/build.gradle`, only `/build.gradle`

Additionally, your [Gradle build plugin is outdated](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: Alternatively, import the other folder as a module of the root. It's possible to have gradle-modules without a gradle-root (got a project like that)

Comment: @cricket_007 I feel like this is close to the right answer.  I just don't know how to do this using bitbucket while still being able to access the repo remotely.  Whenever I open the main folder on bitbucket it looks very similar to the image you posted, but I can't clone it at that level, instead of "clone" the button says "check out" and when I click it, instead of a link to the repo, it simply says "git fetch && git checkout master".  So what I've been trying to do the whole time is import the project from bitbucket, but make my project root that of the level that your image suggests.

Comment: You cannot manage it within Android Studio VCS window from that inner directory and you cannot clone only a folder. You alternatively need to use an external Git client (Github Desktop, SourceTree, terminal, etc.)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you so much for your help these past couple of days.  I went ahead and got SourceTree set up and was able to import my project using the correct modules while having VCS integrity using SourceTree.  Bitbucket and SourceTree must be going steady right now.  I was finally able to make some run configurations.  I learned a lot today!  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok but if you open that subfolder, the app will build properly, but then android studio is not able to access the files that are parent to that folder. And think a bunch of dependencies are broken and read every file with hundred of error.

Answer (score 0):

The top level should look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The app level file should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'
def JacksonVersion = '2.6.0'
def GPSVersion = '6.5.87'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) //This is where your JARs go

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.0.0'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

You need to remove the `android-apt` plugin from it because the functionality is already included. If you later run into trouble, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016596/apt-dependency-scope-in-android-gradle-what-is-it-used-for).