# Problem importing a source code to android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

everytime i try to import a code source to android studio here's what  i get:

[image]

but on a youtube video here's what he got:

[image: java, assets and then you find in the bottom "gradle script"]

I tried using another code source but it still didn't work.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161858/5566935) may help you

Comment: could you please simplify his answer since i didn't exactly know what I got to do.

Comment: If you're importing existing source code of Gradle project, then try to use File -> Open and choose `build.gradle` file. Android Studio should automatically suggest you to import it as a project and if you choose to do so - you should have project correctly imported as Gradle project.

Comment: i don't think you realize... how much i love u brother